# Why can we quantize based on rindler time coordinate, when Rindler time may not be timelike?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

It is easy to note from Rindler diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#/media/File:Rindler_chart.svg) that Rindler time may not be timelike. But we still quantize by treating Rindler time coordinate as "time" - Unruh effect is demonstrated that way.

So does this mean that we can quantize quantum field theory by selecting time as any coordinate axis without necessitating checks on timelike vector field? What is wrong with this understanding?

Comment: Could you provide an example? I’m looking at that svg chart and I don’t see how the Rindler time coordinate can ever be space-like.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I may be misunderstanding things, that's why I am trying to clarify. In the svvg chart, a trajectory can be at same T, yet Rindler time t increases, so trajectory is spacelike... Also, http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/3-Rindler.pdf says that Rindler time translations are boosts in Minkowski spacetime, which I understand as boost vectors such as $x\partial_t + t\partial_x$, and at $x=0$, this collapses to being spacelike.

Comment: That doesn’t mean that the coordinate is not timelike though! In normal Minkowski space there’s space like trajectories among which time increases, too! You have to keep the other coordinates constant and only vary Rindler time, and it is impossible for such a trajectory to be spacelike.